# Can't get JQuery show to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner with javascript and I just can't seem to figure something out.

I'm trying to show an overlay div using jquery. Here's what I have

```
$("#loginbutton").click(function() {
    alert('Ola');
    $('#overlay').show();
    return false;
  });
```

The accompanying css for the overlay

```
#overlay {
z-index:1000;
position:fixed;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#000;
opacity:0.45;
-moz-opacity:0.45;
filter:alpha(opacity=45);
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Pressing the login button will show the alert but not the div. Has anyone got a clue why this is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
display:none;
```

instead of

```
visibility:hidden;
```

Comment: Awesome! Will accepts as soon as stackoverflow lets me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change `visibility:hidden` to `display:none`

---

I believe the $.show() function is shorthand for the `display:block` attribute which would replace your `display:none`

However, if you have `visibility:hidden` then it will remain hidden

Answer (score 0):

`display:none` should work fine

Answer (score 0):

you may but this calling for click event when document is **completely loaded**
so try

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#loginbutton").click(function() {
       alert('Ola');
       $('#overlay').show();
       return false;
     });
   )};
```